# Error in Using GPML Toolbox in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying to run a sample code which uses the GPML Toolbox in Octave. As suggested in the README, I ran the startup.m file as suggested [here.](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/code/matlab/doc/) But this results in the following error:

```
executing gpml startup script...
warning: addpath: /cov: No such file or directory
warning: called from
    startup at line 8 column 15
    /usr/local/Cellar/octave/4.2.2_1/share/octave/4.2.2/m/startup/octaverc at line 31 column 3
warning: addpath: /doc: No such file or directory
warning: called from
    startup at line 8 column 15
    /usr/local/Cellar/octave/4.2.2_1/share/octave/4.2.2/m/startup/octaverc at line 31 column 3
warning: addpath: /inf: No such file or directory
warning: called from
    startup at line 8 column 15
    /usr/local/Cellar/octave/4.2.2_1/share/octave/4.2.2/m/startup/octaverc at line 31 column 3
warning: addpath: /lik: No such file or directory
warning: called from
    startup at line 8 column 15
    /usr/local/Cellar/octave/4.2.2_1/share/octave/4.2.2/m/startup/octaverc at line 31 column 3
warning: addpath: /mean: No such file or directory
warning: called from
    startup at line 8 column 15
    /usr/local/Cellar/octave/4.2.2_1/share/octave/4.2.2/m/startup/octaverc at line 31 column 3
warning: addpath: /prior: No such file or directory
warning: called from
    startup at line 8 column 15
    /usr/local/Cellar/octave/4.2.2_1/share/octave/4.2.2/m/startup/octaverc at line 31 column 3
warning: addpath: /util: No such file or directory
warning: called from
    startup at line 8 column 15
    /usr/local/Cellar/octave/4.2.2_1/share/octave/4.2.2/m/startup/octaverc at line 31 column 3
```

I tried to search online for resources that guide you through the installation, but could not find any resource. Any help on this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: I gues you've only extracted the startup.m and not the whole archive?

Comment: @Andy I was able to resolve the issue by manually adding the path of all sub-folders to octaverc. I guess, the startup.m must have failed due to some reason.